# Deleting the grandchild of copied object will remove it from the original object

Tags: javascript, object

In the following code snippet, I want to remove part of the object using the `removeItem()` function.
There is no problem when I delete the first level child of the object but when i delete second and more level children this value is also removed from the `originalObject` while I want to make no changes to the `originalObject`.

```js
let originalObject = {
    name : 'Jack',
    job: 'teacher',
    friends : 10,
    car : {
        name : 'pride',
        color : 'white',
    }
};

function removeItem(obj) {
    let copiedObject = Object.assign({}, obj);
    delete copiedObject.friends;
    delete copiedObject.car.color;

    return copiedObject;
}

let newObject = removeItem(originalObject);

console.log(newObject);
console.log(originalObject);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try to use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`, as object does not have any functions:

```
function removeItem(obj) {
    let copiedObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
    delete copiedObject.friends;
    delete copiedObject.car.color;

    return copiedObject;
}
```

An example:

```js
let originalObject = {
    name : 'Jack',
    job: 'teacher',
    friends : 10,
    car : {
        name : 'pride',
        color : 'white',
    }
};

function removeItem(obj) {
    let copiedObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
    delete copiedObject.friends;
    delete copiedObject.car.color;

    return copiedObject;
}

console.log(`originalObject before`, originalObject);
let newObject = removeItem(originalObject);

console.log(`newObject`, newObject);
console.log(`originalObject after`, originalObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you are doing is a [shallow copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Cloning_an_object), if you want to have a complete separate copy of your objects, then you have to do a [deep clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone) like the following code snippet:

```js
let originalObject = {
    name : 'Jack',
    job: 'teacher',
    friends : 10,
    car : {
        name : 'pride',
        color : 'white',
    }
};

function removeItem(obj) {
    let copiedObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
    delete copiedObject.friends;
    delete copiedObject.car.color;

    return copiedObject;
}

let newObject = removeItem(originalObject);

console.log(newObject);
console.log(originalObject);
```

Check this [article](https://www.codementor.io/@junedlanja/copy-javascript-object-right-way-ohppc777d) for more information about object cloning

Answer (score 1):

"For deep cloning, we need to use alternatives, because Object.assign() copies property values."

"If the source value is a reference to an object, it only copies the reference value."

[Detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)